# Continuous Non negative martingale converging to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Is there any (non trivial) continuous non negative martingale which converges to 0?

Comment: Which convergence do you want? Almost sure, $L^1$, in probability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, try $M_t=B_{t\wedge T}$ where $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion starting from $B_0=1$ and $T$ is the first hitting time of $0$ by $(B_t)$.